# problems with downloading lyx to a mac with m1 chip

Tags: errors, lyx, mac

I recently switched from pc to mac, specifically I have mac with a M1 chip. I've tried to download lyx a few times. first I downloaded mikitex and that wasn't a problem, then I downloaded LyX/Mac 2.3.6.2 from the main website. every time I tried to finish the installation I received this error: "Lyx can't be opened because cannot check it for malicious software. the software needs to be updated. contact the developer for more information".

what did I do wrong? from where and how can I download lyx? if it's not possible - whar other editors of latex will work on my mac?

[image: error message]

Comment: That's probably due to macOS' safety settings: open settings -> safety -> general, there should be stated that the installation of LyX has been prevented, via the lock to the bottom left in the window you can "unlock" the option to install it (I hope the translations of the names is right or can at least guide you on the right path). Regarding your other question: I was using the MacTeX installation, but switch to TeXStudio (still in combination with Tex Live)

Comment: could you post this as an answer so i could mark the question to have been answered? @Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably due to macOS' safety settings (I had similar problems with other programs too):

open settings -> safety -> general, there should be stated that the installation of LyX has been prevented, via the lock to the bottom left in the window you can "unlock" the option to install it.

Regarding your other question: I was using the MacTeX installation, but switch to TeXStudio (still in combination with TeX Live)